# Enterprise Chef Server to Open Source Chef Server

Tags: chef-infra, knife

I have a chef server(Ver 11.0.8) configured and running in Centos 6 which have 60+ nodes configured, and I'm also using its web-ui, recently I upgraded the chef-server to 12.0.3 and I got this notification at top of the page as follows,

**This installation is managing 68 nodes, but is only licensed for 25. Please upgrade now to ensure proper licensing.**

I believe what I'm running is an enterprise chef server, if it is so, how can I change it to open source chef server?

This setup was done by someone previously and now this task of upgrading and management is given to me and I'm quite new to CHEF.

Before upgrading I did not see this notification, if I uninstall web-ui it will be open source server again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, chef 12 has no longer an enterprise and open source version, it's open source.

The change is that the open source web-ui has been abandonned in favor to the commercial one.

All enterprise add-ons are free up to 25 nodes, above you need to get a license (even if it won't stop working, but be fair ;) ).

Uninstalling the web-ui (formerly chef-manage) will remove the warning.

Comment: Thanks Tensibai, 
If I remove the web-ui, it ll become open source?? so that I can use it without license for more than 25 nodes? 

Or rollingback to chef server 11 web-ui will make it as open source?

Comment: Just remove the webui, the chef-server itself is opensource. It's the webui only that is licensed See [Here](https://www.chef.io/chef/#plans-and-pricing)

Comment: You're welcome, consider marking the answer as accepted (it helps triaging in question list)